# how to create an instance of a superclass with attributes?

Tags: python, oop

I have the classes below and I want to create an instance of Celebrity that is also a Person and has an age attribute.  As I have it I'm pretty sure morganFreeman is a Celebrity but not a Person; how do I instantiate so that he an instance of both subclass and superclass and has attributes of both?

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age = age
class Celebrity(Person):
    def __init__(self,profession):
        super(Celebrity,self).__init__(profession)

morganFreeman = Celebrity("actor")
bob = Person(45)
```

Comment: `morganFreeman`'s age is `'actor'` because you are passing it through the super to the init of `Person`

Comment: `self.Person = self` is of no use, remove it.

Comment: Oh.  How would I write it so that I can define both attribute's values in instantiation?

Comment: @kvivek: how are peopple supposed to see what the O.P. got wrong and explain it thoughtfully in an answer if you ask for edits fixing the code in the question? In time, the question would display working code and have no point at all. Please, indicate the errors you find in questions' code in your answers, not asking for correction (or worse, editing them yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept the `age` parameter in the `__init__()` method in `Celebrity` and then pass that to the base class `__init__()`:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age = age

class Celebrity(Person):
    def __init__(self, age, profession):
        self.profession = profession
        super(Celebrity, self).__init__(age)

morganFreeman = Celebrity(55, "actor")
bob = Person(45)   

>>> bob = Person(45)   
>>> morganFreeman = Celebrity(55, "actor")
>>> morganFreeman.age
55
>>> morganFreeman.profession
'actor'
>>> bob.age
45
>>> bob.profession
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'profession'
```

This shows that `Celebrity` objects have both `age` and `profession` attributes, whereas `Person` attributes only have `age`.

Comment: In python3, `super().__init__(age)` ?

Comment: I'm sure he is... but with all the cosmetic surgery that the acting profession are partial to, maybe he looks 55?

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. Follow up question though, what would I add if I wanted to another subclass as a child of Celebrity with its own attribute too?

Comment: @user3150635 : just follow the same pattern. Accept the extra attribute as an argument to `__init__()`, bind that argument to an instance variable (i.e. `self.blah = blah`), then call the base class `__init__()` with super and the arguments required for that class which in this case would be `age` and `profession`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `self.Person = self` is nonsense; `self` is already `self`, of course.

Secondly, your assumption is wrong. `morganFreeman` is both a Celebrity and a Person. That's how inheritance works, by definition.